# Error inside Android NDK r10e while porting application

Tags: android, android-ndk, libstdc++

While I am trying to port my project on latest Android NDK r10e, got the following error

```
/devtools/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/codecvt.h:398:11: error: redefinition of 'class std::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>'
     class codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>
           ^
/devtools/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/codecvt.h:340:11: error: previous definition of 'class std::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>'
     class codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>
```

Any idea why I am getting this and how to workaround?

Comment: Do you have a minimized test case?

Comment: Not in hand. Trying to prepare one for you...

Comment: I don't know what's going on here, but when I have tried to create a minimal code, I have found that _inclusion_ after one of my project file causes the problem. Reordering the inclusion removes the error! Any Idea why?